# How to make a list of the roots of a polynomial equation without the ``x ==" s in each entry?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
        List @@ Roots[x τ (-1 + τ^2) (-1 + 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) (-1 + τ^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(b\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) (Subscript[b, 1] - 
      Subscript[c, 1]) (τ^2 Subscript[b, 1] - Subscript[c, 
      1]) (-1 + 
      Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[c, 1]) (-1 + τ^2 Subscript[b, 1]
        Subscript[c, 1]) (x τ - Subscript[c, 
      2]) (τ^2 Subscript[b, 1] - x Subscript[c, 2]) (-1 + 
      x τ Subscript[c, 2]) (-x + τ^2 Subscript[b, 1]
        Subscript[c, 2]) (x τ - Subscript[c, 
      3]) (τ^2 Subscript[b, 1] - x Subscript[c, 3]) (-1 + 
      x τ Subscript[c, 3]) (-x + τ^2 Subscript[b, 1]
        Subscript[c, 3]) == 0, x]
```

gives

```
    {x == 0, x == Subscript[c, 2]/τ, 
 x == (τ^2 Subscript[b, 1])/Subscript[c, 2], 
 x == 1/(τ Subscript[c, 2]), 
 x == τ^2 Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[c, 2], 
 x == Subscript[c, 3]/τ, 
 x == (τ^2 Subscript[b, 1])/Subscript[c, 3], 
 x == 1/(τ Subscript[c, 3]), 
 x == τ^2 Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[c, 3]}.
```

I would like to have a list of the roots without the `x==` in each entry. How can I remove this?

Comment: Calling your list `lst` use e.g. `lst[[All, 2]]`.

Comment: Thanks! That exactly answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Artes will not elaborate and since questions should have answers posted as such, I will volunteer to try to write one.

Let's call your result `lst`. In *Mathematica* all things, however rendered, are functions wrapped in functions. Those equality signs? Actually a function called `Equal`.

To extract some part of an output it helps to know exactly how the expression we're dealing with looks and for this purpose we have `FullForm`.

```
lst // FullForm
```

Gives

```
List[Equal[x,0],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],-1],Subscript[c,2]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],2],Subscript[b,1],Power[Subscript[c,2],-1]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],-1],Power[Subscript[c,2],-1]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],2],Subscript[b,1],Subscript[c,2]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],-1],Subscript[c,3]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],2],Subscript[b,1],Power[Subscript[c,3],-1]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],-1],Power[Subscript[c,3],-1]]],Equal[x,Times[Power[\[Tau],2],Subscript[b,1],Subscript[c,3]]]]
```

Artes retrieved all elements on the first level and the second element on the second level using `Part` (`lst[[All, 2]]`). We can easily see from the `FullForm` that this is possible. Your list is just a list of `Equal` elements and the relevant part is the second argument to those list elements.

Most of all, peaking at the expression with `FullForm` often makes it very easy to find patterns that match what you want to extract, you could do

```
lst /. Equal[__, x__] -> x
```

and you would get the same thing.